# How to stop light table using spaces instead of tabs

Tags: ide, tabstop, lighttable

How do I stop Light Table IDE from replacing tabs with spaces? I have tried adding the following line the editor behaviours in user.behaviours but it hasn't worked.

```
(:lt.objs.editor/tab-settings true 4 4)
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should actually work. I put that line into a vanilla Light table installation and I get tabs, not spaces. It doesn't replace the spaces you have but the new ones are tabs.

Here's my config from user.behaviours:

```
 ;; The editor tag is applied to all editors
 :editor [:lt.objs.editor/no-wrap
          (:lt.objs.style/set-theme "default")
          (:lt.objs.editor/tab-settings true 4 4)]
```

Comment: Looks like I had to clear my AppData for LightTable too.

Comment: It doesn't appear to work anymore, atleast not for the html editor. It does however work in the user.behaviours file.

Comment: Okay, to fix it I also needed to add the same under :editor.html, I have no idea why.